# Connect extra 4 SAS HDDs to HPE Proliant Dle360 gen9

Tags: sas, hpe

I have an HPE Proliant Dle360 gen9 configured with 1x 500w PS, 32GB ram, 1x 12 core Xeon cpu.

At the moment its 4 front bays are occupied by 4 SAS HDDs. I want to replace them with 4 SAS SSDs and also reconnect the 4 SAS HDDs some other way.

Do I have the necessary connectors for SAS data and power on the motherboard? Would a SAS to SATA solution work?
As a last resort, if there's no way to get power I could add an external normal PC PS with molex power connectors.

Comment: how should we know about? If this is built by HP take the serial and ask the support of the vendor, it may be easier as trying here to ask a glass ball ;)

Comment: Buy a server that has the connectivity you need.